# Encrypt S3 buckets that Serverless framework creates for deployment

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, serverless-framework

Is there a way to automatically encrypt the cloudformation buckets that serverless framework creates? I would like to ensure that the cloudformation s3 buckets are private and encrypted when we run e.g. `sls deploy`

Comment: Could you post the code snippet?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it already enables SSE for deployment buckets. See https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/5800